# Installing several Printers to several PCs with different Settings on a single Network

Tags: networking, printing

I have a Network, on which are 5 Printers and 5 Pc's. Every Pc has its own printer. I need to install each Printer on each Pc with different Settings. Is there good efficient way to do it without having to manually install the printer on each pc using Control Panel and its Device/Printer settings?

Answer (score 2):

> Note that is question is off topic and not related to code and
>   therefore doesn't belong to SO.

But you may want to take a look at [this](https://www.printeradmin.com/printer-management/print-management-console/). You could set up, for example, a server and add the printers to the Print Management there. This way you can manage all of them via the  Print Management of the server.

However, this requires all printers to be network compatible.

[Here](https://www.faqforge.com/windows-server-2012-r2/install-configure-print-server-windows-server-2012-r2/) is a guide to set up a Printserver.